# Not able to login to IBM websphere console

Tags: websphere

In Websphere, on Security settings, I changed the flag `"Trim Kerberos realm from principal name"` and now I am trying to log to websphere console, it keeps saying error `Invalid user id or password`.

Check the SystemOut.log file, it shows below error

```
An unexpected exception occurred when trying to run getUserDN() method : GSSException: com.ibm.ws.security.auth.kerberos.NoCredentialFoundException: Did not find user in userRegistry for userName: wasadmin@abccompany.com
```

What are different options I can try to login to console successfully?

Comment: Your security configuration is probably messed up.Did you fully and correctly configured Kerberos/SPNEGO authentication? Is your wasadmin user in the LDAP? What attribute are you using for login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your security setting are and why the login is failing after enabling the setting. But if you want to get into admin console to fix your security setting, you can disable security as follows temporarily.

To disable security, please perform the following steps via wsadmin:

```
<WAS_INSTALL_DIR>/bin/> wsadmin -conntype NONE.
wsadmin> securityoff.
wsadmin> exit.
Restart the servers.
Enable the security from administrative console.
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405302